# What are these two superhero(?) images that potentially look like the James Webb Space Telescope?

Tags: object-identification

This Nancy Grace Roman Space Telescope [tweet](https://twitter.com/NASARoman/status/1502307739330088963?cxt=HHwWhsC4ob27otkpAAAA) says:

> I wonder if they will let me hang up my favorite superhero posters in the @NASAGoddard  cleanroom? I cannot wait to join these fantastic telescopes! Is there an application that I need to fill out to join the team @NASAExoplanets?

and includes the first image below. I normally try to describe what images look like within posts; to me it looks like a one-giant-eye'd squid-bird with no tentacles.

A [reply tweet](https://twitter.com/zxqwy/status/1502378657716838409) by Yalın Özer @zxqwy who claims to be "mostly harmless" shows without any text a roughly similarly-shaped green creature with (probably) two eyes and scale-like plates.

**Question:** What are these two superhero(?) images that potentially look like the James Webb Space Telescope?

---

click for full size:

[image: https://twitter.com/NASARoman/status/1502307739330088963] [image: https://twitter.com/zxqwy/status/1502378657716838409]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The one on the left (posted from the [Nancy Grace Roman Space Telescope official twitter account](https://twitter.com/NASARoman?ref_src=twsrc%5Egoogle%7Ctwcamp%5Eserp%7Ctwgr%5Eauthor)) appears to be a 'superheroified' version of their telescope.

[image]

NASA Goddard's [reply](https://twitter.com/NASAGoddard/status/1502321476434898946) that they're "*already a superhero in our book*" would seem to confirm this, as would this [latest image from the same account](https://twitter.com/NASARoman/status/1504170657692758026/photo/1)

[image]

---

The one on the right, posted in reply by Yalın Özer isn't a superhero, it's a Pokémon called [Metapod](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Metapod_(Pok%C3%A9mon)) that he presumably thought looked similar.

Comment: Similar? The outline is uncanny. I honestly think that the webb superhero image might be an altered frame of the pokemon manga that shows metapod in that pose or something. The light rays in the background look like the classic "who's that pokemon" background from the anime.